# Angular JS Camera plugin base64 string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to use camera plugin with cordova app in ionic angular.js. My problem is that when i get picture it gives me a url of image not base64 string
I need base64 string.
in Services.js

```
.factory('Camera', function($q) {

   return {
      getPicture: function(options) {
         var q = $q.defer();

         navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
            q.resolve(result);
         }, function(err) {
            q.reject(err);
         }, options);

         return q.promise;
      }
   }

});
```

I user code above this returns

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/cache/1313513121.jpg

but I want base64 string because I send it to server to save the image in server
in Controller.js

```
$scope.AddImage = function () {
         var options = {
         quality : 75,
         targetWidth: 200,
         targetHeight: 200,
         sourceType: 1
         };

          Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
              alert(imageData);
              var item={
                  image: imageData
              }
             Pictures.push(item);
             $scope.Photos = Pictures;
          }, function(err) {
             console.log(err);
          });
    }
```

I wrote code above. How can I solve this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`destinationType`** option parameter with value **`DATA_URL`** on the `[ cameraOptions ]`.

> navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [
>   cameraOptions ] );

The option `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` will allow you to take a photo and retrieve the Base64-encoded image.  Default this is set to `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` which will retrieve the image file location.

Below a general code sample which you can use to adapt your existing code.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.6.0/cordova/camera/camera.getPicture.html)

Comment: I tried to add in controller.js in options but not worked

Comment: It should... It's hard to detect were the problem is , but try the above as a test code sample ... Try to change also to `navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );` instead of the `.then` appraoch.